# migrate code using C99 dynamically allocated multidimensional arrays into C++

Tags: c++, c99

I'm in the process of trying to learn how to do things in C++, and one of the aspects with which I'm grappling is how to efficiently implement dynamically allocated multidimensional arrays.

For example, say I have an existing function:

```
void myfunc(int *lambda, int *D, int *tau, int r[*tau][*D])
{
  int i, j, k, newj, leftovers;

  r[0][0] = *lambda;
  j = 0; // j indexes the columns; start with zero
  for(i = 1; i < *tau; i++){ // i indexes the rows
    leftovers = *lambda;
    for(k = 0; k < j; k++){
      r[i][k] = r[i - 1][k]; // copy prior to j
      leftovers = leftovers - r[i][k];
    }
    r[i][j] = r[i - 1][j] - 1; // decrement
    r[i][j+1] = leftovers - r[i][j]; // initialize to the right of j

    if(j == *D - 2){ // second to last column
      for(k = 0; k <= j; k++){ if(r[i][k] != 0){ newj = k; } }
      j = newj; // can't think of a better way to do this
    }else{
      j++; // increment j
    }
  } // next row please

}
```

From what I've read, it seems a common recommendation is to use std::vector for this purpose. Would anyone care to offer some advice or code snippet on how to implement the r matrix above using the std::vector equivalent?

I would have thought this is a fairly common situation, but interestingly, google turned up fewer than 50 hits for "C99 into C++".

Thank you!
Ben

Comment: Why did you search for "C99 into C++" when that's not what you actually want?  Did you try searching for `std::vector example`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be about the most straightforward conversion:

```
void myfunc(int *lambda, std::vector<std::vector<int> > &r)
{
  int i, j, k, newj, leftovers;
  int tau = r.size();

  r[0][0] = *lambda;
  j = 0; // j indexes the columns; start with zero
  for(i = 1; i < tau; i++){ // i indexes the rows
    int D = r[i].size();
    leftovers = *lambda;
    for(k = 0; k < j; k++){
      r[i][k] = r[i - 1][k]; // copy prior to j
      leftovers = leftovers - r[i][k];
    }
    r[i][j] = r[i - 1][j] - 1; // decrement
    r[i][j+1] = leftovers - r[i][j]; // initialize to the right of j

    if(j == D - 2){ // second to last column
      for(k = 0; k <= j; k++){ if(r[i][k] != 0){ newj = k; } }
      j = newj; // can't think of a better way to do this
    }else{
      j++; // increment j
    }
  } // next row please
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have numerous options.

---

The quick change:

```
void myfunc(const int& lambda, const size_t& D, const size_t& tau, int* const* const r) {
  ...
```

---

Using a `vector` (which will not enforce matching sizes at compilation):

```
void myfunc(const int& lambda, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& r) {
    const size_t tau(r.size()); // no need to pass
    const size_t D(r.front().size()); // no need to pass
    ...
```

---

Or using `std::array` for static sizes:

```
enum { tau = 5, D = 5 };
void myfunc(const int& lambda, std::array<std::array<int,D>,tau>& r) {
  ...
```

---

Or using template parameters for fixed sizes:

```
template < size_t tau, size_t D >
void myfunc(const int& lambda, std::array<std::array<int,D>,tau>& r) {
  ...
```

or just:

```
template < size_t tau, size_t D >
void myfunc(const int& lambda, int r[D][tau]) {
  ...
```

---

Note that you can also combine static and dynamic sized arrays as needed in C++.

---

Finally, Multi Arrays are here to help you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: Thank you for the plethora of options. Is std::array specific to C++11 ?

Comment: @user2397939 you're welcome. its standardization precedes C++11. `std::array` is a tr1 extension -- which places its introduction around 2006. it was derived from `boost::array`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1

Answer (score -1):

I would change all r[x][y] to R(x,y) and use

```
int * r;
#define R(x,y) r[ (x) * (*D) + (y) ]
```

Or maybe change *D to *tau, I can never keep those straight.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I read two questions (1) how to port this? (2) maybe vectors would help?